# Best way to implement a global variable for use in class in c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

Please read the question before marking it as a duplicate.

So here is what I am trying to achieve. Basically I have a string which contains some value initially. 
I have split my program into many classes for modularity.(you can suggest a better way to do that - currently each file contains one class in it)
 So say for eg I want to operate on the data with class1 , then the modified string needs to get operated by class2 and so on.


eg.
 Initial entry is "hello world"
first class -> "hello WORLD"
second class -> "H@l@o WORLD"
thiid class -> "#@l@o WORLD"
and so on...

 Reading everywhere that global variables are a big no no when coming to issues and downsides it has. So keeping that in mind what would be the best way I can share seamlessly between classes.
I also thought of passing the string as a pointer to each function but I thought there might be better alternatives to it. Please suggest.

Thanks for stopping by to read my que and help me out.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with global variables. Give think they are just encouraging us not to be lazy, which is good. One thing you can do is put that variable as protected in a base class. THEN all your other classes inherit from the base class. They will now all have access to the base class variable.

Comment: I thought that but how would it be possible that they all share the same data of base class (same value throughout) when individual object of each class is created ?

Comment: Ah, of course.  Too early in the morning. Sorry.

Comment: any other solutions you can think of? thanks

Comment: Usually a global is a cheap dodge that will be regretted later, but if the entire point of the variable is to have a single variable modified by multiple modules, classes, or what have you, a global variable may be the easiest to read and maintain solution. In this case though the input to class2 is the output of class 1. That's pretty specific and ordered. Sounds  to me like a good time to pass the value along as a parameter.

Comment: In the MFC environment I sometimes store these kind of values in the main app class as private variables and provide public read/write methods to access it.

Comment: another solution I thought of is global object of a class which stores just this member and make other class its friend  so others can access it with the global obj. ??

Comment: The global object just needs public methods to access the private variable.

Comment: that's why I said I would declare all the other classes as Friend class of that data class (so they can access the private member using obj)

Comment: If it's a complex application as you mention in comment you probably should provide proper communication between classes than single global variable. But it's actually hard to tell without a context if you should have global instance of a class. Your example is so trivial that you should use builder pattern similar to what Chris Drew proposed for it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly *why* you want to do this it is hard to answer. But I don't see what is wrong with just passing the `string` as a reference to each class much like you suggest:

```
class StringModifier1 {
public:
  void operator()(std::string& s) {
    // modify s...
  }
};
class StringModifier2 {
public:
  void operator()(std::string& s) {
    // modify s...
  }
};
class StringModifier3 {
public:
  void operator()(std::string& s) { 
    // modify s
  }
};

int main() {
    std::string myString = "hello world";

    StringModifier1 modifier1;
    StringModifier2 modifier2;
    StringModifier3 modifier3;

    modifier1(myString);
    modifier2(myString);
    modifier3(myString);
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9IQ0GrNlK4bSB92D)

In some cases you might want the classes to store a pointer or reference to the string:

```
class StringModifier1 {
private:
 std::string& s;

 void func1() { 
     // modify s... 
 }
 void func2() { 
     // modify s some more...
 } 
public:
  StringModifier1(std::string& s) : s(s) {}

  void execute() { 
      func1();
      func2();        
  }
};

int main() {
    std::string myString = "hello world";

    StringModifier1 modifier1(myString);
    modifier1.execute();

    StringModifier2 modifier2(myString);
    modifier2.execute();

    StringModifier3 modifier3(myString);
    modifier3.execute();
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1upWq5LUwOArJpHM).

You might want one class to own and provide access to the string and the other classes have a pointer or reference to the owning class.

Comment: This was my last option already as I mentioned in the que.. do you have other good suggestion? can you check my last comment on que and suggest if it is a good way

Comment: @KushanMehta Well, I can't see anything wrong with it. Can you?

Comment: Why use classes at all?  Just need three functions that take a string and return a modified string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm assuming in practice the three classes have some internal state, otherwise yes, just use three functions.

Comment: Its actually a pretty use and complex program and hard to explain the purpose so demonstrated it as follow. Using classes is almost a necessity because I will have like 50 other similar function not just 3 and data hiding is also important as I dont want direct access to my code

Comment: @ChrisDrew even I cant find anything wrong with it but each class will have atleast 10 different functions so passing to each of them would be cubersome when the 1 function of class calls the other 9.

Comment: @KushanMehta I've added an alternative that you might prefer in that case.

Comment: @ChrisDrew thanks for all the efforts.  another solution I thought of is global object of a class which stores just this member and make other class its friend so others can access it with the global obj. Can you tell me which one is better considering huge amount of functions and classes

Comment: @KushanMehta I would avoid global variables and `friend` if you can.

Comment: @ChrisDrew so how much less effiecient would it be to have a private member that is char [][] in each individual classes and then having a parametric constructor which sets the pointer address for the private member of that particular class. btw I am dealing with char [ ] [ ]  in my case and not exactly strings. Thanks

Comment: @KushanMehta I wouldn't use global variables for reasons of efficiency if that's what you mean.